# A mixed-up puzzle from a mixed-up aunt

Tags: word

Your mysterious aunt (not uncle!) sent you a computer for your birthday, but it seems to be password protected. Your aunt has sent you a riddle and a set of instructions for finding the password and unlocking your new computer.

---

The instructions:

> The password of this computer will only be granted by solving this puzzle. The phrases describe the word that is your password; each line has one word that is mixed up! Put the words back in place and find your password.

The riddle:

> Originating thousands of large ago
>
> I thrust in the sky
>
> Soaring above the years
>
> Propelled by clouds
>
> Or by letters
>
> I am infinitely fly
>
> But just five muscles long

---

You must get both the original riddle and the answer correct, partial earns an upvote.
*This is my first time trying this, please tell me if the difficulty is fine!*

Comment: I think the story is a nice touch, and scrambling the lines was a great layer to add onto what would otherwise have been just another (decent) riddle. However, the instructions on unscrambling the lines could have been more cryptic or subtle. The community is probably smart enough to figure out what is needed with just a few hints instead of being told outright that the lines have been scrambled. Good effort though, +1!

Comment: @Xenocacia Thanks for the advice! I am always trying not to make the puzzle too easy but not too hard either:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual riddle should read:

> Originating thousands of $years$ ago
>  I $fly$ in the sky
>  Soaring above the $clouds$
>  Propelled by $thrust$
>  Or by $muscles$
>  I am infinitely $large$
>  But just five $letters$ long

As suggested by @Ankoganit, the answer to the riddle is probably:

> Plane
>  1. The concept of a plane in geometry was formulated by Euclid, back in 300BCE, more than 2000 years ago.
>  2. Aeroplanes fly in the sky, above clouds, propelled by thrust (difference in air pressure between top and bottom surfaces of wings)
>  3. Planes of movement categorize how our muscles exert force
>  4. In geometry, a plane is an infinitely large 2D surface
>  5. "Plane" is 5 letters long.

Comment: Maybe the answer is ([rot13](http://www.rot13.com/))Cynar ?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct riddle.

Comment: And you got it! Also, @ankoganit thanks for scrambling it in the comment